# Can I specify a default schema when creating a PGPoolingDataSource?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi

I would like to be able to reference tables in my code without having to specify the schema name each time (since I'd like the schema to be a configuration parameter).

I'm using the JDBI library, and it requires a DataSource object, so I'm creating a `PGPoolingDataSource`, but I can't find any way to specify a default schema when configuring it.

Comment: You can `alter` the user that you use to connect to and define  a (permanent) `search_path` for that login

Comment: With "default schema" you refer to the database name you want to switch to or query from, respectively?